# Trouble to call a bash command from vimrc with autocommands | "Error: no previous command" (neovim)

Tags: autocmd, neovim, bash

basically i want to test within my vimrc, if `/home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets` was symlinked to `/home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/snippets`
If not, it should create the symlink.

**the code:**

```
au VimEnter * :!bash -c "! [  -L /home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/snippets  ] && ln -sb /home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets /home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/snippets"
```

The `":"` before `!bash` doesn't change anything.

**the error message:**

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":                                                                                              
E34: No previous command
```

My problem is, i don't know what is wrong with my code and google/help pages also aren't very helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!` has to be escaped which can be done with a backslash `\!`.

I think the problem comes from the second bang in your command which has a special meaning for vim. It is automatically replaced with the previous external command.

> Any '!' in {cmd} is replaced with the previous          external command
> (see also 'cpoptions').  But not when             there is a backslash before
> the '!', then that            backslash is removed.  Example: ":!ls" followed
> by            ":!echo ! ! \!" executes "echo ls ! !".

And since the autocommand is triggered by the `VimEnter` event, which means as soon as vim is launched, there can't be any previous external command.

You should probably escape the second bang to protect it from being interpreted by vim before the command is sent to the shell :

```
au VimEnter * :!bash -c "\! [  -L /home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/snippets  ] && ln -sb /home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets /home/$USER/.dotfiles/nvim/snippets"
```

For more information, see `:help :!`.